# [Qt]How to support :pressed state of style sheet for custom widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

***What i have :-***

I have a custom widget which extends QFrame (instead of QWidget as QFrame already has a working paintEvent implementation). I have overridden the mousePressed() and mouseReleased() to emit the pressed() released() and clicked() Signals. Everything upto this point is woring fine as expected.

***What i need :-***

This custom widget is having basic style sheet support and it supports the :hover state just fine.
But the :pressed state is not working. I have already figured out that this is bcoz its not supported by QFrame/QLabel etc. 
I wish to know what do i need to do in order to support the :pressed state.
Should i set some attribute / property on pressed and released OR anything else ?

Comment: Just quick question. Is there any particular reason for using QFrame instead of QPushButton, QToolButton or QAbstractButton as base class?

Comment: Yes. I need to be able add more widgets into it and set a layout which QFrame supports well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a property to your `QLabel` (or whatever widget you are using) and change the value of that property. Then you use that property in your stylesheets.

Example:

```
this->setStyleSheet("*[myproperty=\"true\"] { background-color: red }");
d_label = new QLabel("dynamic label", this);
d_label->setProperty("myproperty", false);
```

Then in your mousePressEvent you set and in mouseReleaseEvent you unset that property:

```
d_label->setProperty("myproperty", true); // or false when you wish to unset it
style()->unpolish(d_label);
style()->polish(d_label); // force a stylesheet recomputation
```

Comment: I was expecting Qt to have an attribute/property which represents the :pressed state. But i guess not. This does the job until Qt decides to add it.

Comment: You, Sir, just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "setStyleSheet()" in the mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent with the style that you want ?

Comment: Yes.I have that for the moment. In fact, i'm getting the current style sheet String extracting the :pressed part of the string and setting it in the mousePressed() and restoring the normal style sheet in mouseReleased() as a workaround. I'm looking for a proper solution as there are multiple custom widgets i need to do this with.